# Discord.py bot only processes one event at a time?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made a basic internet scraping bot (specifically, one that would go to goodreads, and scrape information about the requested book). Since it has to do a fair bit of scraping (and perhaps because I'm hosting it on my laptop itself), it takes around 10 seconds for each request.

I noticed that if I entered two requests right after each other, it executed the second one only after finishing the first one. How would I make it run them in parallel? I read something about shards, but that seems to be for multiple servers (and that too only on 100 servers or so). Right now its only on one server (my testing server).

Update: As per an answer, I can use aiohttp instead of requests to do what I want to do. I could use some help regarding the aiohttp equivalent of this code:

```
sess = requests.session()
req = sess.get(i) #i is a url
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('a')['href']
print(link)
with sess.get(link, stream=True) as req2:
    with open(os.path.join('C:\\save\\location', f"{file}.txt"), "wb") as x_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(req2.raw, x_file)
```

Where `file` is a variable initialised earlier. Essentially what is happening here, is that I am writing the contents of a download file into a text file in the desired directory.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use `requests`, Using `requests` in an async function causes the whole code to block, resulting to usage of another command only after 1st one completes. Prefer using `aiohttp` instead of `requests` as it provides async support for HTTP requests.

Read more about `What blocking means?` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)

Example:

```py
import aiohttp

URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/hot.json?limit=10"

async with aiohttp.request("GET", URL) as response:
    # Check if the request was vaild.
    if response.status == 200:
        # Converts response into dict.
        json_data = await response.json()

        # Gives you plain text.
        text_data = await response.text()

    else:
        print(f"The request was not successful\nStatus code: {response.status}")
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll read up on this, implement it and get back to you!

Comment: Hi! I looked up aiohttp, but could not quite get it. COuld you perhaps explain what would be the equivalent code snippet when using aiohttp?
```r = requests.get(link)```
```page=r.text```

Comment: Hi, sorry to trouble you again. I've updated the question with a specific piece of code I need help with.

Comment: P.S: Everything else is working perfectly, by the way, thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that!

Comment: So if its possible, could you have a look at the updated questions — the one bit I'm still having some trouble with?